# Apply-templates which recurse Elements that contain attribute values to reference another Element

Tags: recursion, xslt, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I am having difficulty applying templates to an Element which is the result of a selection of Elements by an attribute.

The code is essentially attempting to recurse an Element which contains other elements referenced by a name attribute.

The xml 'design' is not mine to change. The goal is to figure out how many widgets (eg: data fields) it would take to represent all the fields and 'contained' fields in a "page" Element.

Given **has_depth.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root> 
<page name="Locale" page_type="VIRTUAL">
    <datum name="lat"><type name="double" complex='0'/></datum>
    <datum name="lon"><type name="double" complex='0'/></datum>
</page>
<page  name="how_many_fields_do_i_have" page_type="CONCRETE">
   <datum mnemonic="foo"><type name="int32" complex='0'/></datum>
   <datum mnemonic="foo_locale"><type name="Locale" complex='1'/></datum>
</page>
</root>
```

and **find_depth.xslt**:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//page[@name='how_many_fields_do_i_have']" />
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page" >
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="concat('getting depth for page ',@name)"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:variable name="depth">
            <!-- ask the Page's first datum for its depth --> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./datum[1]" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="concat('It would take ',$depth,' widgets to show this page in a gui')"/></xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datum[./type[@complex='0']]"  >
    <xsl:message> <xsl:value-of select="concat('matched simpletype:',current()/type/@name,':',@mnemonic)"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:variable name="below"> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='current()=last()'><xsl:value-of select='0'/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::datum"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message> <xsl:value-of select="concat('depth after simple ',@mnemonic,': ', 1 + $below)"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:value-of select='1 + $below'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datum[./type[@complex='1']]" >
    <xsl:message> <xsl:value-of select="concat('matched complextype:',./type/@name,':',@mnemonic)"/></xsl:message>
    <!-- start depth again recursing into the page[type="'VIRTUAL'"] -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//page[@name='./type/@name']" />
<xsl:if test='current()!=last()'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::datum"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following when the bash command: `xsltproc find_depth.xslt has_depth.xml`

```
getting depth for page how_many_fields_do_i_have
matched simpletype:int32:foo
matched complextype:Locale:foo_locale
depth after simple foo: NaN
It would take NaN widgets to show this page in a gui
```

Where I would expect the output:

```
getting depth for page how_many_fields_do_i_have
matched simpletype:int32:foo
matched complextype:Locale:foo_locale
getting depth for page Locale
matched simpletype:double:lat
matched simpletype:double:lon
depth after simple lon: 1
depth after simple lat: 2
depth after simple foo: 3
It would take 3 widgets to show this page in a gui
```

It looks like things go sour when I try to `apply-templates` to `Locale` after selecting it by `./type/@name` which evaluations in the message statement too "Locale" (see between colons in the 3rd line of the output statement.) However to be sure I linted using `xmllint --xpath "//page[@name='Locale']" has_depth.xml` and found:

```
xmllint --xpath "//page[@name='Locale']" has_depth.xml 
<page name="Locale" page_type="VIRTUAL">
    <datum name="lat"><type name="double" complex="0"/></datum>
    <datum name="lon"><type name="double" complex="0"/></datum>
</page>
```

which is as I expect.

Questions is:
**How can I get this thing to recurse as one would expect and treat the sums as numbers as recusion bubbles up?**

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement in words - not by showing long  code that doesn't.

Comment: okay edited, explanation at top. Initialy I was trying to avoid the wide aperature of 'solving my problem' and focus more on the xml paradigm b/c clearly I'm missing something basic. HIH

Comment: I am afraid I still have no clue what are you trying to accomplish. Maybe others will be able to help you.

Comment: Hmm, 2nd try: I would like to know the number of times there is a <type> element in the definition of the page Element named "how_many_fields_do_i_have". The correct answer in my use case is 3. Is that a better explanation?

Comment: No. In your example, both `page` elements have exactly 2 `type` descendant elements. I don't know know what "in the definition of" means .

Comment: it's a strange document. The 2 type instances defined in "how_many_fields_do_i_have" are simple and complex (see @complex). If the types attribute for complex is true, then the type@name is used to look up the definition of the complex type. Any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this very confusing, but maybe the following stylesheet can give you some starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="page" match="page" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page[@name='how_many_fields_do_i_have']"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($temp)"/>
    </result>
 </xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="type[@complex='0']">x</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="type[@complex='1']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('page', @name)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>3</result>
```

Of course, this is no more than a wild guess intended more to clarify the problem than to solve it.

Comment: I like your approach of using a key instead of another xpath. Also regarding tallying the "x"s to keep track of fields as a string length. Interesting. Is it not possible to simply add integers as the stack returns? For example if the type also had a @bytes attribute where doubles are 8 and int32s are 4. The total would be 20 (8+8+4). Thoughts?

Comment: What would you add these integers to? When there are multiple nodes to continue the recursion, the path "splits up" - so each branch would count only its own nodes.

Comment: It *is* possible to let each `type` create a node in the `$temp` variable with a numeric value, and then sum these. But you would need to convert the variable from a result-tree-fragment to a node-set first. My method of leaving a string "footprint" avoids this complication.

Comment: I realized ... I was having a paradigm issue. I was thinking of the output of templates like a function 'return value' for the calling template. It is not. It is directly output to the document. So it is impossible to pass back a number to be added to because it doesn't exist in memory to add to. It exists as the current output on the page. Don't know how I got in this thought turbulence but I did. I'm wondering if I should delete this issue so as not to lure others into the same confusion. Thoughts?

Comment: I think others could learn from it.